# Drop a role with privileges

Tags: sql, postgresql, rdbms, roles, database-administration

This looks like a very basic need, but I do not find any quick and suitable answer. I have a role in Postgres which has privileges to many other tables in various databases.

I need to drop this role. I have one postgres instance and then many databases on top of it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 'REVOKE ALL ON TABLE ' || table_schema || '.' || table_name || ' FROM ' || r.param_role_name || ';'  
FROM information_schema.table_privileges CROSS JOIN (SELECT 'some_role_name'::text AS param_role_name) r
WHERE grantee ~* r.param_role_name;
```

I can do like above, by going to each and every database and find all revoke statements and then drop the role. Is there any way I can find all revoke statements at one place for all the databases.

Or something like I can alter owned by this role, can I alter all privileges with one statement?

Edit1: As most of the replies are targeted to reassign owned by and drop owned by, I want to be more specific.
I can execute below commands on each database and drop the roles once all the dependencies are removed.

```
REASSIGN OWNED BY some_role_name TO postgres;
DROP OWNED BY some_role_name;
```

but there are many databases so I am looking for something forcefully flush all privileges and drop this role.

Comment: The procedure is described [in the documentation.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/role-removal.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I need to drop this role.

Run this in every database of the same cluster where the role might own anything or have any granted privileges:

```
REASSIGN OWNED BY some_role_name TO postgres;
DROP OWNED BY some_role_name;
```

`postgres` being the default superuser, you can pick any other. It is going to own objects currently owned by the old role. Immediately after [`REASSIGN OWNED`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-reassign-owned.html), there are no objects left that would be *owned* by the same user. It may seem unintuitive to run [`DROP OWNED`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-drop-owned.html). The wording of the command is misleading, since it *also* revokes all privileges and default privileges for the role in the same database. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-drop-owned.html)

> `DROP OWNED` drops all the objects within the current database that are owned by one of the specified roles. **Any privileges granted to the given roles on objects in the current database and on shared objects (databases, tablespaces) will also be revoked.**

Bold emphasis mine.
You still have to execute it in ***every single database*** where the role owns anything or has any granted privileges. The manual:

> Because `REASSIGN OWNED` does not affect objects within other databases, it is usually necessary to execute this command in each database that contains objects owned by a role that is to be removed.

Finally, run (once):

```
DROP role some_role_name;
```

Roles are stored in a cluster-wide system catalog, while ownership and privileges on objects are stored in database-local system catalogs.

Detailed explanation in this related answer:

- [Find objects linked to a PostgreSQL role](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/155356/3684)

There is a related [page in the manual with instructions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/role-removal.html).

### Full automation

There is no single command to do it all. But you can let Postgres generate a complete psql script for you.

Dependencies for roles are stored in the system catalog [`pg_shdepend`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-shdepend.html):

> This information allows PostgreSQL to ensure that those objects are unreferenced before attempting to delete them.

Since we (potentially) need to connect to different databases, we need a combination of psql meta-commands (`\c my_database`) and SQL DDL commands as shown above. Create this function somewhere in your DB cluster once:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_generate_ddl_to_remove_role(dead_role_walking regrole)
  RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
SELECT concat_ws(
   E'\n'
 ,(SELECT string_agg(format(E'\\c %I\nREASSIGN OWNED BY %2$s TO postgres; DROP OWNED BY %2$s;'
                          , d.datname, dead_role_walking)
                   , E'\n')
   FROM  (
      SELECT DISTINCT dbid
      FROM   pg_shdepend
      WHERE  refobjid = dead_role_walking
      ) s
   JOIN   pg_database d ON d.oid = s.dbid)
 , format(E'DROP role %s;\n', dead_role_walking)
   )
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT f_generate_ddl_to_remove_role('some_role_name');
```

Produces a string like:

```
\c my_db1
REASSIGN OWNED BY some_role_name TO postgres; DROP OWNED BY some_role_name;
\c my_db2
REASSIGN OWNED BY some_role_name TO postgres; DROP OWNED BY some_role_name;
DROP role some_role_name;
```

Or, if the role does not own anything and has no privileges, just:

```
DROP role some_role_name;
```

If you provide a non-existing role name, you get an error.

Copy the string (without enclosing single quotes) to a psql session opened with a superuser like `postgres`. Or concatenate a bash script with it. All done.

There are several related answers with more explanation for dynamic SQL:

- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bplpgsql%5D+%5Bdynamic-sql%5D+string_agg

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am already doing this but there are many databases and I don't want to execute same commands on each of them, looks like there is no other way!

Comment: @user3294904: Yes, you need to execute in every involved database. But you can let Postgres generate the whole script. I added a chapter above. And you do not need `REVOKE ALL ON TABLE ...` like you display in the question, since `DROP OWNED` takes care of all privileges.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot drop a role until there are dependent objects in any of the database.

You will have to reassign the objects owned by this user (some_role_name) to another user.
Once it is done for all objects in all the databases, you can then delete the user.

`REASSIGN OWNED BY some_role_name TO some_other_role_name;`

If the dependent objects are not required, you can also go ahead using DROP OWNED BY, removing all the object that are owned by some_role_name.

`DROP OWNED BY some_role_name;`